# using partition from multiple tables in view

Tags: sql, hadoop, view, hive

Say I have two tables:

tablea (id int, dt string)
tableb (id int, dt string)

I want to be able to create a view joining these two tables, but reference the partition.

```
create view viewa 
partition on (dt) 
as
select  
    a.id, a.dt
from 
    tablea a
    join tableb b on a.id = b.id;
```

When trying to query this view I get an error:

```
select * from viewa where dt >= '2012-01-01';
```

No partition predicate found for Alias tableb:b.

How can I ensure that when I query this table that both tables are being filtered using the overall partition i.e. both tables use the dt partition in the where clause of my statement?

Thanks.

Comment: are you really wanting to use a join, or did you mean to have a *union* of the two tables?

Comment: I wanted to use a join